# Backbone - trying to make a filter on a collection with nested object

Tags: backbone.js

i'm trying to filter a collection which has models with some nested object. Unfortunately, my result are always empty.

So my models returned in the collection are build like this:

[image: model]

**My goal is simple:**
I have a view with a list of tag and a content view with all the questions. When a user click on tag, for example, "c#", i want to filter my collection to just return questions with tag "c#"

Before i was doing a fetch on my server and it was working fine, but it was not optimize.

I already have a collection with all the questions so why make a new call, a filter is a better solution i think.

But i didn't succeded with my filter and i don't know if it's possible to do. For now i put my filter in my router because it's more easy to test.

i can't make a filter like this because i have an array of object

```
    getQuestionsByTags: function(query) {

        var test = this.questionsCollection.filter(function(model) {
             return model.attributes.tags.name == query;
        })
        console.log('result');
        console.log(test);
    },
```

So i was thinking to make a loop but my result is always an empty array.

```
    getQuestionsByTags: function(query) {

        var test = this.questionsCollection.filter(function(model) {
            _.each(model.attributes.tags, function(tag) {
                return tag.name == query;
            })
        })
        console.log('result');
        console.log(test);
    },
```

It's maybe simple, but i don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

i've just found a solution that work.

```
    getQuestionsByTags: function(query) {
        var flag;
        var test2 = this.questionsCollection.filter(function(model) {
            flag = false;
            _.each(model.attributes.tags, function(tag) {
                if(tag.name == query) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            })

            if(flag) {
                return model.attributes;
            }
        })

        console.log('result');
        console.log(test2);
    },
```

i put a flag. If he turn true inside the loop, the model has this tag so i return it.
I think it's not very conventional, so if someone have another solution, feel free to post it :)